# How to set Python's default version to 3.0.0 on Mac

Tags: python, path, version

The Python's default version is 2.7.0 on my MacOS,

```
python --version
Python 2.7.16

python3 --version
Python 3.9.9
```

and Python3 has been installed via homebrew, how to make it as default? I want to make it point to the correct directory instead of using alias.

```
type -a python        
python is /usr/bin/python

type -a python3                                       
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
```

Also, it would be very grateful if you can help with pip also! So far only pip3 has been installed.

```
type -a pip 
pip not found

type -a pip3                                  
pip3 is /usr/local/bin/pip3
pip3 is /usr/local/bin/pip3
pip3 is /usr/local/bin/pip3
pip3 is /usr/bin/pip3
```

I don't know why my python2 exists in /usr/bin, where ln is not permitted.
[image: Terminal sreenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Generally doing this **can impact legacy programs** reliant on **Python 2.x**, but the below was taken from a website to **demonstrate how to change the default**.

**How to set Python3 as a default python version on MacOS?**

This has been answered on this website, and the below are snippets from the website

[https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf#:~:text=Change%20Python%20Version%20MacHow%20to%20set%20Python3%20as,how%20it%20should%20be%20done%3A%20More%20items...%20](https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf#:%7E:text=Change%20Python%20Version%20MacHow%20to%20set%20Python3%20as,how%20it%20should%20be%20done%3A%20More%20items...%20)

Look where python is installed & view the output.

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

Change the default python symlink to the version you want to use from above.
Note that, we only need to choose the one that end with python3.*. Please avoid using the ones' that end with **config** or **python3****.*****m** or **python3**.***m-config**. Below command shows how it should be done:

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Close the current terminal session or keep it that way and instead open a new terminal window

```
python --version
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I have added a screenshot in my description. I uninstalled the python3 in homebrew directory. I installed it from official site, and now it exists in the `/usr/local/bin` as you can see. However, I don't know why my python2 exists in a different place `/usr/bin`, where ln is not permitted.